# I'm getting "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, setstate

I'm trying to call a method in Stateless widget but it gives error.

**X Class:**

```
class X extends StatelessWidget { 
  const X({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Divider(height: 5,),

          ListTile(
            title: Text('X').tr(),
            leading: Container(
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
              ),
              child: Icon("x", size: 20, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            trailing: Icon("x", size: 20,),
         
            onTap: _openDialog(context),//This line is problematic! If I remove this line, it does not give any error.
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

   _openDialog(context) {
    return showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('title').tr(),
            content: Text('subtitle').tr(),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('confirm').tr(),
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('cancel').tr())
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

The code explains everything, my aim is clear, the code is clear... So how can I solve my problem? ...

**Detailed error:**

> This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
> framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can
> be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of
> its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because
> the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a
> dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might
> not visit this widget during this build phase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are calling the function `_openDialog` while building the widgets, which in turn builds its own widget which is the `AlertDialog`, you want this dialog to be shown on tap so you should pass a function not call one.

i.e

```
onTap: () => _openDialog(context),
```

or

```
onTap: () {
    _openDialog(context);
},
```

Comment: Thank you!!! The problem is solved.